# Source for this Arizal?

Tags: sources-mekorot, arizal

I’ve heard that Rav Chaim Vital has said in the name of the Arizal that a good deed done in their generation is “worth 1,000 times more” than deeds of previous generations.

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 7):

This might be what you're referring to:

> "א"נ במ"ש מהרח"ו זצ"ל ששאל לרבו דעינינו הרואות בתלמוד ומדרשים שמעשים טובים ומדות וקדושת התנאים ואמוראים הוא דבר מבהיל ולא יוכל האדם בדורנו לעשות אחת מאלף, והשיב לו הרב זצ"ל דעתה גברה מאד הסט"א, והמעט שעושים עתה אלהים חשבה לטובה כהרבה שהיו עושים הראשונים..."

Translation: "Another possibility, in that which was written by our master Rabbi Chaim Vital zt"l who asked his rabbi that "Our eyes see in the Talmud and in the midrashim the great deeds and traits and holiness of the Tannaim and Amoraim which was a frighteneing thing and no man in our generation can [hope to] do one out of a thousand [of what they did]", and his rabbi zt"l answered him that now the forces of impurity have strengthened greatly, and the little that is done now Hashem considers it to be greater than many [of the deeds] done by the earlier generations..."

This is brought by the Chida in [Zeroa Yemin on Avot](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=5295&pgnum=72), among other places.

According to the book [Shevet Meyisrael, Vol. 1, pg. 18](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57400&st=&pgnum=44), the quote is supposed to be from [Shaar Hagilgulim, Introduction 38](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%97), but I couldn't find it there.

Comment: It's right there in Shaar Hagilgulim, Introduction 38.

Answer (score 4):

In [Shaar Hagilgulim, Introduction 38](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%97).

> פעם אחת שאלתי למורי ז"ל, איך היה אומר לי שנפשי היתה כ"כ מעולה כנז"ל,
> והרי הקטן שבדורות הראשונים, היה צדיק וחסיד, שאין אני מגיע לעקבו.
> ואמר
> לי, דע לך, כי אין גדולת הנפש תלויה כפי מעשה האדם, רק כפי הזמן והדור
> ההוא. **כי מעשה קטן מאד בדור הזה שקול בכמה מצות גדולות שבדורות אחרים** כי
> בדורות אלו הקליפה גוברת מאד מאד לאין קץ, מש"כ בדורות ראשונים. ואלו
> הייתי בדורות הראשונים, היו מעשי וחכמתי נפלאים מכמה צדיקים הראשונים.
> ושחז"ל על נח תמים היה בדורותיו, ואלו היה בדורות צדיקים היה יותר צדיק,
> ולכן שלא אצטער על זה כלל, כי בלי ספק יש לנפשי מעלה גדולה על כמה צדיקים
> הראשונים מזמן תנאים ואמוראים:

Translation:

> Know, that the greatness of the soul of the person is not [only]
> dependent on the action of the person, but [also] according to the
> current time period and generation. **Because a small deed that is done
> in this generation, weighs like many great deeds done in different [earlier] generations**...